# How To Get The Key Signature From a MIDI File (Format 0)

Tags: objective-c, macos, coremidi

I've adapted code created by [Gene De Lisa](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/) to extract information about a MIDI file. Note, I'm using Objective C for this, not Swift. I can get information about the time signature, track name, bpm, etc, but for some reason I can't extract the key signature of a MIDI file.

Here's my code:

First I open the MIDI file:

```
-(void) loadSequence {
    NSString *songTitle = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"songTitle"];
    NewMusicSequence(&_sequence);

    //NSURL *midiFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:songTitle withExtension:@"mid" subdirectory:@"Levels"];
    NSURL *midiFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:songTitle withExtension:@"mid"];

    MusicSequenceFileLoad(_sequence, (__bridge CFURLRef)midiFile, 0, 0);
}
```

My understanding is that you parse the tempo track of the MIDI file looking for `kMusicEventType_Meta` event types, which have a value of 5. The time signature is one such type of event, as is the key signature. Here's the code for that:

```
-(void) parseTimeSignature {
    MusicTrack tempoTrack;
    MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(_sequence, &tempoTrack);

    MusicEventIterator iterator;
    NewMusicEventIterator(tempoTrack, &iterator);

    Boolean hasNext = YES;
    MusicTimeStamp timestamp = 0;
    MusicEventType eventType = 0;
    const void *eventData = NULL;
    UInt32 eventDataSize = 0;

    MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasNext);

    MIDIMetaEvent *midiMetaEvent = NULL;
    int val = 0;

    //loop through events in the tempo track
    while (hasNext) {
        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator, &timestamp, &eventType, &eventData, &eventDataSize);
        if (eventType == kMusicEventType_Meta) { //gets the time signature (see http:\//www.somascape.org/midi/tech/mfile.html for info)
            midiMetaEvent = (MIDIMetaEvent*)eventData;
            val = (int)midiMetaEvent->metaEventType;

            if (val == 88) { //this is the value present if the metaEventType is a time signature type
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:(int)midiMetaEvent->data[0] forKey:@"timeSignatureNumerator"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:(int)pow(2, (int)midiMetaEvent->data[1]) forKey:@"timeSignatureDenominator"]; //2 represents quarter notes, 3 reps 8th notes, etc
                //break;
            }
            else if (val == 89) {
                NSLog(@"found key signature!");
            }
            else if (val == 3) { //this value represents the track's instrument name
                NSLog(@"%hhu",midiMetaEvent->data[0]);
            }
        }

        MusicEventIteratorNextEvent(iterator);
        MusicEventIteratorHasCurrentEvent(iterator, &hasNext);
    }
}
```

When I open up the MIDI file in Logic Pro X, I can clearly see a key signature. I've tried adding multiple key signature changes to a single MIDI file, but it never shows that there is any such event.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the key signature is in the tempo track?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure. The issue that I have with all of this stuff is lack of documentation or maybe I’m just not putting all of the existing pieces together properly. According to the MIDI spec, key signature events are `meta events`, as is the time signature. I can access the time signature from the tempo track, so I figured the key signature might be accessible the same way. If not, I’m not sure where it would be. There’s a disconnect between the Apple API and the MIDI spec for me.

Comment: I agree with @Willeke - I've seen MIDI files with tempo tracks that contain only tempo events, and where all other tracks have their own title and key-signature messages. I don't think it _has_ to be in the tempo track just because it's a meta event. I think you'll have to read the tracks with the note data to get their key-signatures - each track can have it's own. (Think orchestral scores, where Bb instruments have a different key-sig from piano or strings. -- I think!?!). I use 'midicsv' to take apart and inspect MIDI SMF files. Good luck!

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the heads up on “midicsv”, that will be an excellent tool to see how to access various bits of a midi file. It’s been a bit cryptic up until now.